# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.layers.preprocessing'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras-layer

After writing this:

```
VERIFICATION_SCRIPT = os.path.join(paths['APIMODEL_PATH'], 'research', 'object_detection', 'builders', 'model_builder_tf2_test.py')
!python {VERIFICATION_SCRIPT}
```

I am getting this error:

> from keras.layers.preprocessing import image_preprocessing as
> image_ops ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
> 'keras.layers.preprocessing'

Comment: the script i run : VERIFICATION_SCRIPT = os.path.join(paths['APIMODEL_PATH'], 'research', 'object_detection', 'builders', 'model_builder_tf2_test.py')

!python {VERIFICATION_SCRIPT}

Comment: Please add the code snipptets so that you can be helped

Comment: Otherwise there's a good chance your question will be closed

Comment: @TimbusCalin i tried to upgrade the keras, it didnt solve the error

Answer (score 1):

This error is because there  is no api named `keras.layers.preprocessing`. The correct name of this api is `tensorflow.keras.preprocessing` and you can import `image` from this api not `image_preprocessing`

Try using:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image as image_ops
```

in place of (incorrect way)

```
from keras.layers.preprocessing import image_preprocessing as image_ops
```

Please check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing) link for more details.